# Custom likes counter with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, scope

I want to make a custom likes counter. For this I have used the following code:

```
var likes = 0;
$('#button').click(function(){
      likes += 1;
      $('#likes').text(likes); //A <p id="likes"> html tag created before
      window.stop(likes);
});
```

The problem is the scope of this function. I need to use the "likes" variable outside the scope to convert it to a php variable and save that value in my mysql database. I've tried several ways, but it has not worked for me. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: convert it to php? How? Do you realize PHP and JavaScript never run together? You will have to submit a form/make an Ajax call to your server.

Answer (score 1):

You just need the ajax part to save it

```
var likes = 0;
$('#button').click(function(){
    likes += 1;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/save.php", 
        data: "likes="+likes, 
        success: function(returnMsg){ 
          $('#likes').text(likes);
          window.stop(likes);
        }
    });
});
```

As for the PHP well the var will be $_POST['likes'] use it to save it

Comment: You might want to mention that adding one like should be handled PHP sided, not rely on what is sent from the client side. Anyone could alter what is sent to PHP.